# Sending a stereo audio stream from the browser to a nodejs server

Tags: node.js, audio, socket.io, audio-streaming, web-audio-api

I am using socket.io to send the raw PCM data from each audio channel like so:

```
this.streamNode.onaudioprocess = (e) => {
  const leftChan = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
  const rightChan = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(1);
  socket.emit('stream_rx_channel1', convertFloat32ToInt16(leftChan));
  socket.emit('stream_rx_channel2', convertFloat32ToInt16(rightChan));
};
```

I am using Web Audio API with a [ScriptProcessorNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/createScriptProcessor) to capture the PCM data from each channel and I emit the left & right channel data separately to the NodeJs server.

However, I need to know of a way to merge the streams back together in NodeJs to create a stereo audio stream that can be sent to google's speech-to-text service. Google automatically transcribes for each channel in the audio stream([check here](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/multi-channel#speech-multi-channel-nodejs)). I need this because the left and right channels in this audio stream are 2 different voices.

I am using Google's [stream recognize](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize) for realtime speech to text transcribing.